# Send WebForm as POST - wrong format

Tags: java, android, post

i have a webpage with a webform. I's basically an input field and a selector, but there are a couple hidden fields. I need to send a POST request to this page (this is a search page basically). I've constructed the request as the following:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 10000);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www3.u-szeged.hu/kereses_terem.ivy");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
httpPost.setHeader("name", "search-terem");             

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qsearch", "601"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("medium-subtype", "meta-KOD"));
//and a lot of other parameters, please read on
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I've captured the sent request with Fiddler2, here is the raw request:

```
POST **************** HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
name: search-terem
Content-Length: 760
Host: ****************
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

qsearch=601&medium-subtype=meta-KOD&meta-KOD=&meta-CIM=&num=20&root-id=epulet&relation-types=child+vchild&medium-type=meta&object-types=etr_epulet&result-order=caption&result-order-direction=ASC&pageloader.preexecute=%09%2Fivy%2Fiem-shared%2Fsystem%2Fgems%2Fform-cye%2Fform-engine.xslt&request.formXML=%25webroot%25%2Fxml%2Fforms%2Fusz-search-terem.xml&request.formAPage=%09start&request.form-save-id=epulet&request.form-save-type=col&request.form-save-enabled=true&request.form-instance=2F58DD5D-BFCC-43A4-9B0C-0BC7BF887242&request.form-save-to-instance=false&request.form-redirect-to=kereses_terem.ivy&request.form-language=hu-HU&request.form-save-language=hu-HU&request.instance-id=2F58DD5D-BFCC-43A4-9B0C-0BC7BF887242&request.formPage=--finish--&cmd=submit
```

If the send the form in the browser, this is the sent request:

```
POST http://www3.u-szeged.hu/object.epulet.ivy HTTP/1.1
Host: www3.u-szeged.hu
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 3033
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://www3.u-szeged.hu
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryuiCLY3ISz0tLmrvg
Referer: http://www3.u-szeged.hu/object.epulet.ivy
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: ivy:state-id:persistent=c9581db3-7a49-4e39-9130-3635b491385b; ivy:state-id:session=271fb66f-9579-4f13-a5b6-56c81dea4206

------WebKitFormBoundaryuiCLY3ISz0tLmrvg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="meta-KOD"


------WebKitFormBoundaryuiCLY3ISz0tLmrvg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="meta-CIM"


------WebKitFormBoundaryuiCLY3ISz0tLmrvg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="num"

20
//and so on
```

This is obviously not the same, therefore the server responds with 0 results. How can i send a POST request like this? Thanks!

Comment: Does the server only accept multipart data? If not you may try 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: No change unfortunately.